# Producing/archiving an overview of a directory structure

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

I try to find a way to make an archive of my ~/ directory so that I can go back in case I've lost something. I've found several recommendations for this. The first being [OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2004020716455773) saying a simple `ls -aR` or re-writing a [tree](http://sumedha.blogspot.de/2012/05/tree-command-for-mac-osx.html).
The problem these two solutions have is that the output doesn't help very much in terms of getting an overview where something was.

Is there anything that is able to produce a visual representation of a directory structure that allows to see what contents were in which directory? A Terminal command? A SVG generator?

EDIT: No GUI tools for the generation of the file please. Viewing the large outputs of `find ~/` and `ls ~/` is cumbersome. Or is it possible to make it easier to view a 70MB text file?

EDIT2: I should probably clarify what I'm trying to do. I recently had my hard disk crash. Fortunately I had an off-site and on-site backup. In the restore however I chose to set the machine up from scratch, which means I had to *very specifically pick what to restore from where*.
Now that I'm done with that, I'm investigating whether it's possible to save the directory structure in certain periods of time in my backup, so that restoring becomes a bit easier. (In case I ever lose a couple days of work, with two different backups at two different stages.)

Thanks in advance,
Zettt

Comment: ls -aR and tree only list the directory structure and do NOT archive - what exactly do you mean - the usual archive tools would include Time Machine, rsync, tar

Comment: A collection of the data I had, not the data itself. As you see in the references links, I'm not looking for a backup.

Comment: Well, what do you want now? It's either a GUI or browsing a huge text file, you can't have both. And text file browsing is rather easy with either TextEdit.app or `less`/`vi`/`emacs`

Answer (score 2):

1. Get [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/). It’s free and awesome.
2. Drag (e.g. your home) folder into Text window: [image: How to drag]
3. Profit!

Comment: I've edited my original post. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`find .` gives a listing of all the folders/files starting from the current directory:

```
pse@Fourecks:/etc/apache2$ find .
.
./extra
./extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
./extra/httpd-dav.conf
./extra/httpd-default.conf
./httpd.conf
./httpd.conf~previous
./magic
./other
./other/php5.conf
./users
./users/pse.conf
```

Comment: find is mentioned in my original post. (in the link on rewriting tree). Anyway, the large text files find or ls produce are so huge that it's hard to get an overview after restoring from a backup where something was.

Comment: `grep something huge-file-list` solves that quite nicely

Comment: That would be very slow.

Comment: Did you try? Even on large directories listings, grep is extremely fast

Comment: Just for the record: Running grep to search for the last line in a 100'000 lines text took about 0.1 sec on my iMac.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works quite reliably. (The applications mentioned in this post are actually links)

[`tdu`](http://webonastick.com/tdu/) is a "visualizer" for the `du` command. Together with `dugroup` (same software package) it's quite useful.

In my scenario I would run `du $HOME > "$HOME/History/$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H-%M") Home History.txt"`.
Then by running `cat 2012-08-07 20-00 Home History.txt | dugroup | tdu` the file structure would be viewable "offline". I've tried [`ncdu`](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu), but it has a bug where it deletes all files the program was started in when given a `du` output file.

Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it.